# Is it feasible to make a musical tesla coil

Tags: high-voltage, tesla-coil

Ive built a couple tesla coils so far, both a slayer and a spark gap (nothing overly complex).  I'm still a student so I dont know a ton about electronics but I have a decent foundation.  Has anyone here made a musical tesla coil before?  I'm considering making one, however, I'm not sure if I will be able to.  Theres not much information online about these; I've only really found one tutorial and it's much larger and more expensive than anything I have the ability to make.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  How should I approach this?

Comment: Other people have. It usually seems to boil down to: 1) make a tesla coil, 2) feed music into it instead of steady power.

Comment: I built a musical Tesla coil recently. It's a dual-resonant solid-state type. In order for the coil to make music it needs to be solid-state, allowing you to turn it on and off at set frequencies to generate the desired musical notes. It's a long, difficult process to build a decent one, it's not something you'll be able to throw together in a weekend.

Comment: Video in case you're interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5hfMokGNfI .
Not one of my best, but it works.

Comment: @immibis That is not at all how it works. Simply changing the power supply *will not* make your Tesla coil musical.

Comment: @DerStrom8 That is literally how ElectroBOOM's one worked. I'm sure it only works for certain types of driver circuits. Other ones might need more sophisticated integration, but the principle is still the same - adjust the power level according to the audio signal.

Comment: I am not familiar with "ElectroBOOM" nor his coil. What was the driver type, do you know? Was it a Slayer? Because I know for a fact that won't work on a DRSSTC and most other SSTCs.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to investigate and contact Arc Attack at http://www.arcattack.com

So, yes, a home brew musical Tesla coil is feasible. Is it for you? Well, we can’t say. However, building a Tesla coil can be very dangerous and depends on your design. If you don’t know what you are doing, you probably should find someone with experience to guide you properly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should start out "cheap/china":
https://www.banggood.com/DIY-Mini-Music-Tesla-Coil-Kit-DC-15-24V-2A-ZVS-Plasma-Horn-Speaker-Single-Tube-p-1203961.html?rmmds=search

Answer (score 0):

In order for a Tesla coil to play music it must be solid-state, meaning transistor-driven. Neither a Slayer Exciter nor a spark gap style will allow you to inject variable audio frequency and cause a change in the output frequency.

Solid state Tesla coils are much more complicated than Slayer or SGTC types and require a lot more work to design, source parts, build, and test. They most certainly are NOT projects for beginners.

I wrote a document following the build of my own musical DRSSTC and it can be found in the link below. Be aware there may be several mistakes and don't put 100% faith in it, but it should help to give you an idea of what is involved in the design of such a coil:

http://teslaunderground.com/Matt/VermonsterMiniBuild.pdf